# Cannot run convolutional.py in anaconda tenserenv

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, cudnn

I have installed tensorflow in an anaconda environment called tensorenv and to test the installation I tried to run one of the examples convolutional.py and the follwing comes up.

```
Initialized!
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:346] Loaded cudnn library: 5005 but source was compiled against 4007.  If using a binary install, upgrade your cudnn library to match.  If building from sources, make sure the library loaded matches the version you specified during compile configuration.
F tensorflow/core/kernels/conv_ops.cc:457] Check failed: stream->parent()->GetConvolveAlgorithms(&algorithms) 
Aborted (core dumped)
```

After initialized it should start the training but this error comes up. Please help

Comment: It seems it wants cudnn v4. How to specify that I want to use cuDNN v5

Comment: AFAIK, cuDNN v5 isn't currently supported. You will have to use cuDNN v4 instead

Answer (score 1):

You have to build from source if you want to use cuDNN v5.

According to the documentation:

> Other versions are supported (Cuda toolkit >= 7.0 and cuDNN 6.5(v2), 7.0(v3), v5) only when installing from sources

Comment: Build from source... Does it mean I have to install tensorflow through source?

Comment: It means you clone the tensorflow github repository, and compile it directly. Cf. [the doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/get_started/os_setup.html#installing-from-sources). The simplest is to change cudNN to v4 though.